# GetX dependency injection will not work if didn't used to render widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

GetX is a bit strange, if I don't use any variables in GetxController or GetxService to render a widget with Obx() coverred, the instances don't get injected correctly, the state disappears, and the hash code of instance get from Get.find() is different every different GetView print().

All my controllers, services use lazyPut() to do dependency injection and put in bindings.

**Binding**

```
class OrderHistoryBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  Future<void> dependencies() async {
    Get.lazyPut<OrderHistoryController>(
      () => OrderHistoryController(),
      fenix: true,
    );
    Get.lazyPut<HistoryRepository>(
      () => HistoryRepository(),
      fenix: true,
    );
    Get.lazyPut<PrintService>(
      () => PrintService(),
    );
  }
}
```

**GetPage**

```
GetPage(
      name: _Paths.orderHistory,
      page: () => OrderHistoryView(),
      binding: OrderHistoryBinding(),
      transition: Transition.fade,
    ),
```

---

For a simple example, let's say I need to keep track of how many GetViews a user has viewed.

To do this I create

**CountPageService**

```
class CountPageService extends GetxService {}
```

Internally, there is only the addCount() method and RxInt or int count = 0.obs; / 0;

This CountPageService will run following code as an initialization

**main.dart**

```
Get.lazyPut(() => CountPageService());
```

For each page I run onInit()

```
final CountPageService countPageService = Get.find();
countPageService.addCount();
```

But this problem causes the state not to inherit when I jump to another GetView, because the CountPageService variable is not shown in any GetView

Honestly, I'm not sure if it's lazyPut that's causing the problem, as a lot of people simply generalize Get.put() and Get.lazyPut() to mean that one creates the instance directly in memory, and the other DIs it only when it's needed or used, and I remember the last time I was in the debugging phase, I tried to change it to GetxService, and then to Get.put(). But as far as I remember, I don't think it worked then [vague impression].

Is there any current documentation out there that specifically describes this? I can't find anything about it. If anyone knows much about the inner workings of GetX, please tell me why, thanks.